# How do we get manual access over the files downloaded by testrigor?

Tags: testrigor

When we download a file via testrigor, how do we get manual access over the files? How to access the files locally to perform validations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access downloaded files click "More details" and there you'll see the list of files like so:

[image]